# I have an error and need eyes to look at a mysql statement

Tags: mysql

```
$query_article = sprintf("SELECT * FROM articles, articles_cat_main 
    WHERE articles.id = %s 
    AND articles.cat_main = articles_cat_main.id_articles_cat_main", 
    $colname_article);
```

Im getting : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND articles.cat_main = articles_cat_main.id_articles_cat_main' at line 1

I can't see anything obvious.. its been a long day.

Thanks

Comment: The Error message does not belong to the sql statement you posted.

Comment: Doesn't look like the query and the error message belong to each other - the part that MySQL complains about isn't in the query you gave. Are you sure this is the exact query that triggers this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM articles, articles_cat_main
WHERE articles.id = %s AND ...
```

And %s is replaced with the content of a variable called $colname_article. Based on the name of that variable, I don't think it contains an integer, that can be inserted there without quotes.

If it is either empty or contains a string without quotes, it will result in the syntax error you saw.

Please note that this kind of dynamic SQL statements is prune to have [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

#### after edit

If the variable is a numeric, just concat instead of using sprintf

```
$query_article = "
SELECT * FROM articles, articles_cat_main 
WHERE articles.id = " . $colname_article . "
AND articles.cat_main = articles_cat_main.id_articles_cat_main";
```

But in either case, if the variable is empty or does not contain anything, your query becomes

```
WHERE articles.id = AND articles.cat_main
```

So it errors out.

#### original

It is very obvious that the PHP you showed is **not** what is being run!

It has a

> **WHERE** articles.cat_main ..

The error message has

> near '**AND** articles.cat_main

Check your code to see what you are really running

Comment: yeah i posted the wrong line of code. I updated with the correct, broken code. thanks

Comment: I'm with you on this. Forgot to challenge the premise and ask if the variable was even defined. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a field in 'articles_cat_main' called 'id_articles_cat_main'. If not, then you have a some stuff to delete and that should fix it.

Comment: It's a syntax error, so MySQL did not get so far to look at the structure of the tables.

Comment: And what about the 'id_articles_cat_main' in the next WHERE condition? Same thing or purposeful?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a `JOIN` to include the second table `articles_cat_main`. So:

```
$query_nextprev = "SELECT * FROM articles JOIN articles_cat_main ON articles.cat_main = articles_cat_main.id_articles_cat_main WHERE articles.active = 'y' ORDER BY articles_cat_main.name_cat_main, articles.`order`";
```

Comment: I posted the wrong line of code. I've updated it with the broken one. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the value in `$colname_article` is what's causing your issue. Most likely that value is not a number but in the query mysql is expecting it to be a number or a column name. Most likely the value is a string. Or it's empty.

You can quote it like this:

```
$query_article = sprintf("SELECT * FROM articles, articles_cat_main WHERE articles.id = '%s' AND articles.cat_main = articles_cat_main.id_articles_cat_main", $colname_article);
```

If you're expecting it to be a string. Or if you want it to be a number you should use `%d` instead of `%s` because then if you have something other than a number you'll get a PHP warning (but the query will still fail)

As a bonus the setup as you currently have it has the potential for a SQL injection attack. You may have other code that prevents that but if not you should escape `$colname_article` with `mysql_real_escape_string()` or better yet use PDO and placeholders which will do the same substitution as you're doing here with `sprintf` and handle the escaping.